# Mathjax regarding question - how to type "n-1" in subscript/superscript

Tags: support, mathjax

How can I write a power (n-1) subscript (n-1)

This is what is happening when I try `$$(a_(n-1))^(n-1)$$`
$$(a_(n-1))^(n-1)$$

Comment: `$(a_{n-1})^{n-1}$`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Additionally, when you see an answer with a mathematical notation you don't know how to replicate, you may simply edit the answer to see the actual code. I learnt quite a few tricks this way. (conversely, it's not difficult to find an answer that exhibits the syntax you are asking for)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need [curly braces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Curly_bracket) `{}`. If you write `$(a_{n-1})^{n-1}$` you get $(a_{n-1})^{n-1}$. You can use double dollars to get a centered formula; `$$(a_{n-1})^{n-1}$$` gives $$(a_{n-1})^{n-1}.$$

If the subscript or superscript is only one character, you do not need them. For example: `$a_2^\alpha$` and `$a_{2}^{\alpha}$` give the same result:
$$a_2^\alpha \qquad\text{vs.}\qquad a_{2}^{\alpha}.$$
The first one needs less characters (less typing).

The relevant part in [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) ([current revision](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/5020/100)) is the point "5. Groups".

(This was already explained in comments. I thought that it might be worth to make this also into an answer.)